# How to correctly add a spinner on macOS Catalina as Style.spinning is deprecated?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, appkit, nsprogressindicator

I always create a spinner with `NSProgressIndicator` like this

```swift
let spinner = NSProgressIndicator()
spinner.style = .spinning
```

It works fine, but I recently found the
[NSProgressIndicator.Style.spinning](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsprogressindicator/style/spinning) is deprecated. I have went searched around, but did not quite find out what is the recommended way right now to create a spinner on macOS. Can anyone please help here?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried starting and stopping the indeterminate indicator as suggested here? https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgIndic/Tasks/IndeterProgIndic.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000113-CJCBJJJJ

Comment: Sorry, I don’t think I quite understand this. I have tried to set my indicator as indeterminate, but the shape is a progress bar. My problem is how can I make it a spinner instead of a bar

Comment: Do you get a build error or warning?

Comment: Hi, no, there’s no warning or error at all. I just suddenly found this is deprecated, and trying to find out the recommended way after the depreciation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like an error in the documentation. In macOS 10.15 `NSProgressIndicatorBarStyle` and `NSProgressIndicatorSpinningStyle` are deprecated. Somehow `NSProgressIndicatorStyleBar` and `NSProgressIndicatorStyleSpinning`, `.bar` and `.spinning` in Swift, were also deprecated in the documentation but they aren't in NSProgressIndicator.h.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, NSProgressIndicatorStyle) {
    NSProgressIndicatorStyleBar = 0,
    NSProgressIndicatorStyleSpinning = 1
};
```

and

```
/* Please instead use the more modern versions of these constants.
 */
static const NSProgressIndicatorStyle NSProgressIndicatorBarStyle API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("NSProgressIndicatorStyleBar", macos(10.2,10.14)) = NSProgressIndicatorStyleBar;
static const NSProgressIndicatorStyle NSProgressIndicatorSpinningStyle API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("NSProgressIndicatorStyleSpinning", macos(10.2,10.14)) = NSProgressIndicatorStyleSpinning;
```

Comment: That probably makes sense, as Xcode generally warns about deprecated apis, but I don't get any warning from using the `.spinning` in Xcode. Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

The style isn't deprecated; they've just been making the names consistent so it's easier to turn them into Swift.